# What is the correct usage of "If I were you"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Suppose I am talking to a friend and want to point out that he needs to wash his face before attending an interview. Which of these would be correct?

> If I were you, I would wash your face before attending an interview.

or

> If I were you, I would wash my face before attending an interview.

The second one "feels" correct, but I am not actually washing *my* face so it feels a bit odd to say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second is correct:

> If I were you, I would wash **my** face before attending an interview.

This is because by using *If I were you* you are putting yourself in that position and saying what you would do-  you would wash your face in that situation.

IF you don't wish to tell what you would do and simply state what **they** should do just say:

> You should wash your face before you go.

Or perhaps a combination of the two:

> You should wash your face before you go. I would.